# session array replaces instead of adds to

Tags: php, arrays, session

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["product1"]) && $_GET["product1"] == "Add"){
        $_SESSION['cart']['product1'] = $_SESSION['pricebook']['product1'];
        header('Location: cart.php?');      
        }
    if(isset($_GET["product2"]) && $_GET["product2"] == "Add"){
        $_SESSION['cart']['product2'] = $_SESSION['pricebook']['product2'];
        header('Location: cart.php?');  
        }
 ?>
```

I am trying to allow users to add multiple products to a cart but every time the add button is selected the array (checked using `print_r($_SESSION['cart']`) changes the product in the array instead of adding another product to the array.

Any help/suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: You do have `session_start()` at the top of every file?

Comment: You might need to use an addition sign somewhere + or maybe a push?

Comment: What is `$_SESSION['cart']` and `$_SESSION['pricebook']` before the if-statment?

Comment: `$_SESSION['cart']['product1'][] = $_SESSION['pricebook']['product1'];` and `$_SESSION['cart']['product2'][] = $_SESSION['pricebook']['product2'];` ?

Comment: Yes session_start() is at the top of every file.

Comment: <?php
 $_SESSION['pricebook']['product1'] = array(
 'description'=>'Board my Cat(s)!',
 'price'=>25.95,
 );
 ?>
 
 <?php
 $_SESSION['pricebook']['product2'] = array(
 'description'=>'Board my Dog(s)!',
 'price'=>50.95,
 );
 ?>

Comment: <?php 

if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
 $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
?>

Comment: @asprin that just adds a [0] => Array to print_r but the second product selected still replaces the first so problem is exactly the same still

Comment: Then show us the portion where `$_SESSION['pricebook']['product1']` and `$_SESSION['pricebook']['product2']` are defined. You probably need to add `[]` to these variables

Comment: I tried that but it just keeps adding multiple listings of the same product to the cart instead of adding a second product still. Here is how its defined: <?php
 $_SESSION['pricebook']['product1'] = array(
 'description'=>'Board my Cat(s)!',
 'price'=>25.95,
 );
 ?>
 
 <?php
 $_SESSION['pricebook']['product2'] = array(
 'description'=>'Board my Dog(s)!',
 'price'=>50.95,
 );
 ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand your method but you need to consider changing this 'productX' way of dealing with dynamic stuff.

What i'm doing in my eshop plugin is this: (simplified to meet your code)

```
<?php
// if user added the product named 'product1' by etc. a specific product page
if(isset($_GET["product1"]) && $_GET["product1"] == "Add"){
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'][1])) { $_SESSION['cart'][1] = array("quantity"=>0); }
    $_SESSION['cart'][1]["quantity"] = $_GET["product1_quantity"];
    header('Location: cart.php?');
}
?>
```

Although a much better approach should be something like that:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["product"]) && $_GET["product"]=="Add") {
    $pid = $_GET["product_id"];   // this is one you should add to target the product
    $quantity = $_GET["product_quantity"];   // also, the quantity coming from client
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'][ $pid ])) { $_SESSION['cart'][ $pid ] = array("quantity"=>0); }
    $_SESSION['cart'][ $pid ]["quantity"] = $quantity;  // store the new quantity
    header('Location: cart.php?');
}
?>
```

About the pricing, you should do that by taking into account the quantity of each added product (etc. by a for-loop). *Don't store prices into session* as they're known to you.

Comment: Ok I tried the better approach option and I still have the problem where if I click add to add product1 print_r reads Array ( [description] => Board my Cat(s)! [price] => 25.95 [] => Array ( [quantity] => ) ) and if I try to add another product then print_r reads Array ( [description] => Board my Dog(s)! [price] => 50.95 [] => Array ( [quantity] => ) ) so the cart is still replacing the items instead of adding to the $_SESSION['cart']

Comment: I also tried to array_push($_SESSION['cart'][$pid]["quantity"] = $quantity); with no success

Comment: The products you added above (Cat/dog) they're different right? If yes, they should come  with a `product_id` get parameter you need to add on the cart's page and send as well. This is to differentiate products in session.

Comment: Basically you're sending these parameters from client:  `product`, `product_id` (you need to add it, holding specific id for product), `product_quantity` (etc. a input text holding the quantity text)

Answer (score 0):

```
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_SESSION['pricebook']['product1']);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

your `$_SESSION['cart']` is a multi-dimensional array. the way you have it now `$_SESSION['cart']['product1']` is an element of the `$_SESSION['cart']` array, which you are trying to modify. modify `$_SESSION['cart']` instead to add items to it, not the item inside the cart.